# Plot each column of Pandas dataframe pairwise against one column

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a pandas dataframe where one of the columns is a set of labels that I would like to plot each of the other columns against in subplots. In other words, I want the y-axis of each subplot to use the same column, called 'labels', and I want a subplot for each of the remaining columns with the data from each column on the x-axis. I expected the following code snippet to achieve this, but I don't understand why this results in a single nonsensical plot:

```
examples.plot(subplots=True, layout=(-1, 3), figsize=(20, 20), y='labels', sharey=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with that code is that you didn't specify an x value. It seems nonsensical because it's plotting the `labels` column against an index from 0 to the number of rows. As far as I know, you can't do what you want in pandas directly. You might want to check out [seaborn](https://seaborn.github.io/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html#seaborn.PairGrid) though, it's another visualization library that has some nice grid plotting helpers.

Here's an example with your data:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

examples = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'labels'])
g = sns.PairGrid(examples, x_vars=['a', 'b', 'c'], y_vars='labels')    
g = g.map(plt.plot)
```

This creates the following plot:
[image]

Obviously it doesn't look great with random data, but hopefully with your data it will look better.